# filter("/*).through(PersistFilter.class) does not compile

Tags: wicket, guice

In my code I have the following:

```
private ServletModule getModule() {
    return new ServletModule() {
        @Override
        public void configureServlets() {
            filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);
        }        
    };
}
```

It does not compile allthough it comes straight from the guice-persist site. The error message I get from the compiler is:
    Application.java:[47,28] error: cannot access Filter

Netbeans tells me this:
    method FilterKeyBindingBuilder.through(Class) is not applicable
      (actual argument Class cannot be converted to Class by method invocation conversion)

I checked the code of PersistFilter and it does extend Filter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stupid thing. The servlet api was not being pulled in. Guice-persist needs it